# Php text between two tags

Tags: php, regex, tags

Good evening,

I've a problem with the regular expressions and their using with php.

I need to transform a text between more tags .

For example, this text :

```
Prova prova <Ciao ciao> sto provando {ciao} sto ancora provando [ciao]
```

wold be transformed in

```
Prova prova <<i>Ciao ciao</i>> sto provando {<i>ciao</i>} sto ancora provando [<i>ciao</i>]
```

I need a function that transform in this mode, between tags :
<> [] {}

How can I do it ?

Thank you , and sorry for my english.

Comment: It seems you want to implement your own template engine. Have you considered using something like Mustache PHP? https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)...

```
$text = strtr($text, 
      array('<' => '<<i>', '{'  => '{<i>', '['  => '[<i>',
            '>' => '</i>>', '}' => '</i>}', ']' => '</i>]')
);
```

If you are considering using regex, perhaps you want to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this.

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('~(?<=[<{[])[^]}>]*(?=[]}>])~', 
      function($m) { return '<i>' . $m[0] . '</i>'; }, $text);
```

**Explanation**:

This uses a combination of [lookarounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds). The callback function inserts tags around each match result found.

```
(?<=        # look behind to see if there is:
  [<{[]     #   any character of: '<', '{', '['
)           # end of look-behind
[^]}>]*     # any character except: ']', '}', '>' (0 or more times)
(?=         # look ahead to see if there is:
  []}>]     #   any character of: ']', '}', '>'
)           # end of look-ahead
```

( [`strtr` demo](https://eval.in/176372) **|** [`regex` demo](https://eval.in/176371) )

Comment: I just was about to add this solution. However, the previous one was better, at least to me :) +1

Comment: @hex494D49 thanks, I prefer the callback function, I left it as regex solution.